# Access multiple objects in an object in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to insert values into a realm database in-app. The data returns from the server in a JSON format but with two many objects in an object. I'm able to get first objects inserted but the others I'm finding it hard to do

Sample Data from Server

```
{
  "activeUsers": [

    {
      "id": 1,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "primary": false,
      "fullName": "John Doe",
      "gender": "MALE",
      "primaryContact": "+0011234567",
      "customizations": [
        {
          "id": 17,
          "isEnabled": true,
          "userType": "admin",
          "schedule": {
            "endDate": "2019-12-09",
            "weekDays": [],
            "customWeekDays": [],
            "startDate": "2019-12-13",
            "frequency": "Once"
          },
          "pDate": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to access objects inside the customizations array and insert into the database but with my current implementation the values fail to insert into the fields `frequency and weekDays`

```
this.realm.write(() => {

          Object.keys(data_array).map((key) => {
            new_delegate = {
                id: data_array[key].id,
                full_name: data_array[key].fullName,
                gender: data_array[key].gender,
                primary_contact: data_array[key].primaryContact,
                frequency: data_array[key].customizations[key].others.frequency,
                weekdays: data_array[key].customizations[key].others.weekDays[key].day
              }
              this.realm.create('users', new_users, true)
            })
          })
```

Comment: The `key` variable is for identifying objects inside `data_array`, but you're using it also for `customizations`, where it is not valid. That's why you're having problems with the data inside `customizations`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

frequency is the part of schedule so for customization parent node array you should write

```
data_array[key][0].customizations[0]["schedule"]["frequency"]
```